# Use javascript to convert selectbox to input

Tags: javascript, select, input

Situation I have a form where the user selects from a few options in a select box.

When the user select the option 'other' i want to select box to transform into an input box.

This is my code.

Head

```
<script>
function chargeother(select) {
if (select=="other") {
document.getElementById('chargeother').innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="type">';
} 
}
</script>
```

Body
First Select Box

```
<td id="inputtype">
<select type="text" name="type"  onchange="chargeother(this.value)">
<option value="Labour and Material">Labour and Material</option>
<option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
<option value="Labour Only">Labour Only</option>
<option value="Material Only">Material Only</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Second Select Box

```
<td id="inputhazard">
<select type="text" name="hazard" onchange="chargeother(this.value)">
<option value="No Significant Hazard">No Significant Hazard</option>
<option value="GC43 Attached">GC43 Attached</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</td>
```

I need this function twice on my page is it possible to add an 'id' into the onchange function call

Comment: You’d need to use `.outerHTML`. Not sure why you’re using `.value`.

Comment: Create a new input element, and clone all properties from the select box, and then delete the select box.

Comment: @Xufox thanks that worked. .value works on my other site for filling out a form from a select box. can you post your solutions as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: That's going to make it difficult for a user to change their selection… :-/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Select and Text Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498713/html-select-and-text-input)

Comment: This is not a duplicate a combo box is to advanced for my users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example without target id:

```js
var chargeother = function(el) { // note, its html element
  if ('other' !== el.value) return;
  el.parentNode.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + el.name + "'/>";
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="inputtype">
      <select type="text" name="type" onchange="chargeother(this)"><!-- not just value -->
        <option value="Labour and Material">Labour and Material</option>
        <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
        <option value="Labour Only">Labour Only</option>
        <option value="Material Only">Material Only</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="inputhazard">
      <select type="text" name="hazard" onchange="chargeother(this)"><!-- not just value -->
        <option value="No Significant Hazard">No Significant Hazard</option>
        <option value="GC43 Attached">GC43 Attached</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you notice the 'name' of the input also needs to change?

Answer (score 2):

You needed to specify a `<table>` and `<tr>` tag for `<td>` in the HTML, and use innerHTML on the element and make sure you comment out the double quotes for the attribute values

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function chargeother(ele){
        switch(ele.parentNode.id){
            case "inputtype":
                if(ele.value === "other"){
                    document.getElementById("inputtype").innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"type\">";
                }
                break;
            case "inputhazard":
                if(ele.value === "other"){
                    document.getElementById("inputhazard").innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"type\">";
                }
                break;
        }           
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td id="inputtype">
            <select type="text" name="type"  onchange="chargeother(this)">
                <option value="Labour and Material">Labour and Material</option>
                <option value="Quoted">Quoted</option>
                <option value="Labour Only">Labour Only</option>
                <option value="Material Only">Material Only</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="inputhazard">
            <select type="text" name="hazard"  onchange="chargeother(this)">
                <option value="No Significant Hazard">No Significant Hazard</option>
                <option value="GC43 Attached">GC43 Attached</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>       
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RobG good eye didn't test it with the other values originally... I just update the code above, it works now.

Comment: FYI I didn't include the table and tr elements in my code example because they are not necessary to this question I assume that anyone capable of answering my question would be able to fill in the gaps.

Comment: @JonathanBishop I originally wrote the script without the <table> and <tr> but the selector won't pick up the <td> element's id unless it's wrapped within <table> and <tr>. None-less the above example I believe accomplished what you work looking for?

Comment: @JordanDavis Yes except for the last line of the question, passing the id to the function in order for the function to be used on more than one select box.

Comment: @JonathanBishop Okay then we should use a switch statement... I'll update the code above with a solution... do you have the other select box if so post it above so I can see it's id.

Comment: @JonathanBishop I just updated my code, yeah thats exactly what I thought you meant, check the code I just posted above using the switch statement.

Comment: @JonathanBishop I'll update my code per your values give me 1min.

Comment: @JonathanBishop okay it's update per your values take a look.

Comment: @JonathanBishop cool, yea no problem man, let me know if you need help with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

> ```
>   function chargeother ( select ) {
>    if (select == "other")
>    {
>         var elem = document.getElementById(" selectId ");
>         elem.parentElement.removeChild (elem);
>         var inputElem= document.createElement ('input');
>         inputElem. type='text';
>         document.getElementById (" chargeother").appendChild(inputElem);
>    }
> }
> ```